# Highcharts polygon label

Tags: highcharts, label, polygon

Is it possible to add an label inside a polygon plot?

[image]

I want to add the labels shown in the legend to the polygon plot itself but can't figure out myself how to do this (if it is possible).

Edit:

I added the dataLabel using the dataLabels.formatter like this

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    rotation: 45,
    x: 20,
    y: 0,
    formatter: function() {
        if(_.indexOf(this.series.data,this.point) == Math.floor(circle_template.steps * 0.6)) {
            return "TECHIEK";
        }
    },
}
```

I also added a rotation using the following piece of code:

*Note: I didn't create this, forgot where I found it*

```
function realignLabels(serie) {

    _.each(serie.points, function (j, point) {
        if (!point.dataLabel) return true;

        var max = serie.yAxis.max,
        labely = point.dataLabel.attr('y'),
        labelx = point.dataLabel.attr('x');

        if (point.y / max < 0.05) {
            point.dataLabel.attr({
                y: labely - 20,
                x: labelx + 5,
                rotation: 0
            });
        }
    });
}

Highcharts.Series.prototype.drawDataLabels = (function (func) {
    return function () {
        func.apply(this, arguments);
        if (this.options.dataLabels.enabled || this._hasPointLabels) {
            realignLabels(this);
        }
    };
}(Highcharts.Series.prototype.drawDataLabels));
```

This will result in:

[image]

As I said in the comments, I didn't want to use the bubble chart because I was planning to plot over these plots like this:

[image]

Comment: try using bubble charts

Comment: I would do this by adding a scatter series, with one point for each polygon (or for each desired label), and using its `dataLabel`

Comment: I don't like adding extra data to my graph just for the sake of having the labels. @AsadSarwar, I want to plot more into my graph, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using polygon series, adding dataLabels.enabled: true will add dataLabels to all of your polygon points, not the one polygon shape. Here you can see an example how it can work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/s3zp8cce/

You can add label to your polygon using chart.renderer.label:

```
 function(chart) {
    var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
      yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];
    chart.renderer.label('Target', xAxis.toPixels(165), yAxis.toPixels(60)).attr({
      zIndex: 10,
      'text-anchor': 'middle'
    }).add()
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s3zp8cce/1/

You can also use bubble series, which have label inside the bubble. Here you can see an example how it can work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/cvwf92vj/

Comment: I just need one label and can't use bubble chart because I need to plot more on this graph