# HighCharts polygon label - zoom capable

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a line chart with some background polygons that need labels, much like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583655/highcharts-polygon-label?newreg=545c7e7c90cc487a881adcffce0ee04e). However, my chart uses the zoom capabilities of HighCharts.  The `chart.events.render` will draw new labels on zoom, but it doesn't remove the old ones, which do not zoom either. Using `this.customLabel.destroy()` doesn't seem to do the job. So I end up with excess labels in the wrong places.  How do I remove the old labels with each new render, or is there now a better way to label polygons?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render() {
        const chart = this;
        if (chart.customLabel) {
          chart.customLabel.destroy()
        }
        chart.customLabel = chart.renderer.label('test label', Math.random() * 200 + chart.plotLeft, Math.random() * 200 + chart.plotTop)
          .css({
            color: '#FFFFFF'
          })
          .attr({
            fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
            padding: 8,
            r: 5,
            zIndex: 6
          })
          .add();
      }
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g1v4dwcn/ - resize the viewer in the jsfiddle to see the effect.

Edit by original poster: see comment about "two different SVG Elements"

Comment: Interesting.  That is effectively what I had.  Tried a fiddle of my own and discovered the problem appears when a second label is added.  Problem appears both with resizing as you suggest, or mouse-drag zoom: https://jsfiddle.net/mycobiont/n1zmvrcy/7/

Comment: So with further testing, the last label I add is effectively destroyed and replaced in the correct position.  Any prior labels are just left on the screen.  Here is another fiddle that also shows what I'm trying to do with labeling polygons: https://jsfiddle.net/mycobiont/zcpvLjbk/58/  Note that zooming into Peak 2 works fine as it is the last label I added.  But zooming into Peak 1 results in the old label being left behind while a new label is added - then there are two "Peak 1" labels.

Comment: One more comment: if there is no perfect answer through the HighCharts API, one can remove all elements of class "highcharts-label": 
        var allLabels = document.getElementsByClassName('highcharts-label');
        while (allLabels.length > 0) {
          allLabels[0].parentNode.removeChild(allLabels[0]);
          }

Comment: You have assigned two different SVG Elements (labels) as a one chart object property - your second label reassigned `chart.customLabel`. Try this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hktsbLg3/

Comment: Sebastian, I believe you got it!  Post that as an answer and I'll mark it as 'accepted'.  Thanks!